# How to set new columns in a multi-column index from a dict with partially specified tuple keys?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice, multi-index

I have a pandas dataframe initialized in the following way:

```
import pandas as pd

my_multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a', 'a1'), ('a', 'a2'), 
                                            ('b', 'b1'), ('b', 'b2')],
                                           names=['key1', 'key2']) 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]],
                  columns=['col1', 'col2'],
                  index=my_multi_index)
print(df)
```

which gives:

```
#            col1  col2
# key1 key2            
# a    a1       1     2
#      a2       3     4
# b    b1       5     6
#      b2       7     8
```

Now I'd like to add a new column `desc1` to this dataframe using partial key slicing BUT not in code, I'd like to do this from configuration i.e. a dictionary with partial tuple keys:

```
# i'd like to externalize this and not hardcode it i.e. easier maintenance
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['a', :], 'desc1'] = 'x'
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['b', 'b1'], 'desc1'] = 'y1'
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['b', 'b2'], 'desc1'] = 'y2'
print(df)
```

which gives:

```
# key1 key2                  
# a    a1       1     2     x
#      a2       3     4     x
# b    b1       5     6    y1
#      b2       7     8    y2
```

notice that setting 'x' doesn't depend on the second component of the `('a', _)` key and setting 'y1' and 'y2' do depend on the second component of the `('b', 'b1')` key. A possible solution is to fully specify the mapping but this is also not desirable if I have a 100 `(a, _)` whose assignment doesn't depend on the second component. I wish to reach the above result but not hard-coding the sliced assignments, instead I'd like to do it from an externalized dictionary:

My configuration dictionary would look like this:

```
my_dict = {
    ('a', None): 'x',
    ('b', 'b1'): 'y1',
    ('b', 'b2'): 'y2'
}
```

Is there a pythonic and pandas-tonic way to apply this dictionary with partially specified keys to reach the sliced assignment produced before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can leverage the fact that we can pass tuples as a MultiIndex slicer. Also we slightly adjust your `my_dict`. Then we apply a simple for loop:

```
my_dict = {
    ('a',): 'x',
    ('b', 'b1'): 'y1',
    ('b', 'b2'): 'y2'
}

for idx, value in my_dict.items():
    df.loc[idx, 'desc1'] = value
```

```
           col1  col2 desc1
key1 key2                  
a    a1       1     2     x
     a2       3     4     x
b    b1       5     6    y1
     b2       7     8    y2
```

---

Second option would be to use `Index.map` and filling in the first value in your dict, so we can use `Series.ffill`:

```
my_dict = {
    ('a', 'a1'): 'x',
    ('b', 'b1'): 'y1',
    ('b', 'b2'): 'y2'
}

df['desc1'] = df.index.map(my_dict)
df['desc1'] = df['desc1'].ffill()


           col1  col2 desc1
key1 key2                  
a    a1       1     2     x
     a2       3     4     x
b    b1       5     6    y1
     b2       7     8    y2
```